# Store a path in a variable and use it with cd

Tags: linux, shell

I have a path as,

```
Sample_Backend_Parameterized_Deployment
```

I want to set this path into a variable and call it later. How can I do it?

I tried this and not working

```
CDPATH="Sample_Backend_Parameterized_Deployment"

cd $CDPATH
```

Getting error

> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sample_Backend_Parameterized_Deployment:  No such file or directory

Is there a way to give the path from `{WORKSPACE}/Sample_Backend_Parameterized_Deployment`

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Do you get an error message? Does the current directory not change? Please update your question. The way you're trying to do this seems to be correct and works for me (bash 4.4.19)

Comment: What ls says for the path?

Comment: Use another variable name. `CDPATH` is special in many shells. Yet another reason to not use uppercase variable names.

Comment: Is that the full error? It should be something like `cd: /dir: No such file or directory`. If this is not the full error message, please include it. Also, what shell are you using?

Comment: I am using Jenkins shell, when I used full path as, `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sample_Backend_Parameterized_Deployment` working fine. Is there a way to give the path from `{WORKSPACE}/Sample_Backend_Parameterized_Deployment`

Comment: If you want to update or add to your question, do so by editing the question. Don't do it in comments.

Comment: Jenkins automatically sets the WORKSPACE variable for each project, so why not just do `cd $WORKSPACE`?

Comment: @Haxiel your answer is working. thanks a lot

Comment: @Janith Great, I'll add that as a proper answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a job is executed on Jenkins, a number of context-specific environment variables are also set by Jenkins. These variables can be reused when using the 'Execute shell' build step as well.

Specifically for this case, the environment variable `WORKSPACE` is set to the absolute path of the Jenkins workspace, which is the working directory used during the build process. To change to the workspace directory, you can use the `cd $WORKSPACE` command during the appropriate build step.

A list of all the environment variables set by Jenkins during a job is available at this link: [Jenkins Set Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables)

Comment: yes, this is the definite answer. can you give me the way to navigate from `{WORKSPACE}` to front directories. eg:- `cd ${WORKSPACE}/sample-inventory-backendcode`

Comment: @Janith Assuming that 'sample-inventory-backendcode' is a valid directory inside the workspace, you can do `cd "$WORKSPACE/sample-inventory-backendcode"`.  Are you encountering any issues with that?